Searching all XMLs in a folder that are missing a specific tag, Windows 10?
I have a folder with hundreds of XML files. I Need to search all (*.xml) files to find files that do not contain a specific tag, and somehow present me the list of those XML files missing the tag.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can do this with cmd. The command can be something like:
findstr /v /m \<string *.xml

where /v print lines not containing the string, but combined with /m print files which do not contain string \<string
And based on this answer with powershell
gci -filter "*.xml" | Where-Object { !( $_ | Select-String "<string" -quiet) } | Select Fullname


Thanks Romeo. That does do exactly what I asked for, however I now see I left some other requirements out that would refine this for me... But, it does exactly what I placed for my question. I had not realized I needed to find the missing tag when another specific tag is found within the same branch.

@TravisElijah, If you have more complex request (for search) probably will be better to just ask new question.

@TravisElijah, maybe you can check xmllint and using xpath way to search for more complex logic

Remember that a simple grep that looks at files as text, rather than as XML, will miss some subtleties. For example, it's not looking at namespaces; it will find an element even it appears in comments or CDATA, and it's not looking at elements that are "virtually present" in the file because of XML entity expansion. It's possible that those concerns don't matter for your use case.

Using Saxon's Gizmo tool from the command line (disclaimer: I wrote it) you can do
/>show uri-collection('dir?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')[not(//tag)]

and of course the predicate in the square brackets can be an arbitrary XPath 3.1 expression.
